# Kali linux network connection icon missing

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux

I was trying to setup a vpn connection in `Kali linux` but i don't know what did i do that network connection icon (screen top right) is missing and i can't connect to internet! How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I search for an hour and finally try  `debian` network packages and it worked! So i put here if someone had same problem can fix it.
Download [this debian network packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=network-manager) and install in Kali(dpkg -i package.deb) then reboot.

Comment: But how do you download it if you have no internet because you can't connect because you can't open the network manager?